# Iterate a list for a second time

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a page produced with thymeleaf and I iterate through a sections list to create buttons for each section. Later in the same page I want to iterate the same list again but I get a null error

```
<div class="sections">
    <div th:each = "section: ${chapter.getSections()}" th:text= "${section.getTitle()}"/>
</div>

.
. // Later on the code 
.
// This is where I get the null exception trying to call section.getContent()
<div th:each = "section: ${chapter.getSections()}" th:insert="${section.getContent()}"/>
```

Comment: Please provide more details about error including full stack trace and Java code where you create model for page. It is possible that a `NullPointerException` is thrown in `getContent()` method (or literally anywhere else as there are a lot of possibilities)

Comment: Side note: You should be able to use field names based on JavaBeans naming standards in your Thymeleaf expressions - so, for example `${chapter.sections}` instead of `${chapter.getSections()}`.